# Calling thread from test method :code is optimized or a native frame is on top

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void FileNetInThreadTest()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(Go);
            System.Threading.Thread t2 = new System.Threading.Thread(Go);

            //t1.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
            //t1.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);

            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
        }

        private void Go()
        {
            var documents = TestDtos;
            foreach (var x in documents)
            {
                UnderTest.StoreDoc(x);
            }
         }
```

The StoreDoc call a COM component internally.
On the that com call I get an ThreadAbortException
When I try see the details of the exetion I am getting
"Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call 
stack."

What could be the reason?

Comment: Same result even if i un comment the commented lines

Comment: Threading is not a minor detail in COM, it knows whether a COM component is thread-safe, the vast majority are not, and it will ensure that the component is used in a thread-safe way.  Even if you try to use it from a worker thread.  Which for one means that you don't actually get any concurrency so is rather pointless.  For another it means that your program can crash when the required proxy/stub is missing.   Setting the apartment to STA is not a workaround, the object is still owned by whatever thread created it.  Why you don't get a better exception is hard to guess.

Comment: Did you check that your code is not optimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that is because unit-tests did not start with `[STAThread]`? If your main-program use the com-object and you use `[STAThread]`, does it work than?